# Can I select particular processes/sockets tracked via Phoenix Presence?

Tags: websocket, elixir, phoenix-framework, user-presence

My use case is to have multiple users connected to a lobby/waiting room, but only two of them will be picked from the lobby to start a conversation, after which they should be removed from the lobby. How can I implement that? Note that in this system the users aren't registered and don't have usernames. They should directly come in from the webpage.

Apparently the `track` and `untrack` functions also have variants that accept `pid` as an argument. However I'm not sure how I can retrieve the pids of the processes in the first place, when the conversation needs to be started.

Is the function `self()` the correct one to use in this case? i.e. maybe I can write

```
def handle_info(:after_lobby_join, socket) do
  Presence.track(socket, "lobby", %{
    pid: self()
  })

  {:noreply, socket}
end

def handle_info(:start, socket) do
  pid1 = hd(Presence.list(socket)["lobby"][:metas])[:pid]
  # Start the conversation by sending messages individually to pid1 and pid2
  ...
  untrack(pid1, "my_app:lobby", "lobby")
  {:ok, socket}
end
```

Or am I overcomplicating the issue/not understanding Presence correctly?

There's also a `phx_ref` field but I don't seem to be able to use it for this purpose.

Also, apparently I would only want to send `"start_conversation"` messages to the two users being picked but not the others in the lobby. I see that the function `push` sends messages to a designated socket. But if I am keeping track of the pid, can the corresponding sockets be identified from the pid?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my initial question using individual user channels eventually. I just let the frontend generate random user IDs.

A solution without using user channels is proposed [in Elixir forum](https://elixirforum.com/t/phoenix-websocket-how-to-send-message-to-one-user/10668/12). It doesn't use Presence though.

```
def handle_info({:new_user, socket}, [{us1, ref1}, {us2, ref2}]) do
  # we had 2 users, a new one joined, so that's 3
  user_sockets = [socket, us1, us2]
  # we can create a room for them now
  create_new_room(user_sockets)
  # and clean the state
  Enum.each([ref1, ref2], fn ref ->
    Process.demonitor(ref)
  end)
  {:noreply, []}
end

def handle_info({:new_user, socket}, waiting_user_sockets) do
  # otherwise just add the new users to the waiting users list
  ref = Process.monitor(socket)
  {:noreply, [{socket, ref} | waiting_user_sockets]}
end

def handle_info({:DOWN, ref, :process, _object, _reason}, waiting_user_sockets) do
  # remove the disconnected socket
end
```